# Help understanding pivoting and port forwading

Tags: meterpreter, port-forwarding, proxychains, pivoting

I am trying to learn about pivoting/port forwarding and how to take full advantage of it. If I am connected to a network with the ip `192.168.0.10` and can see that `192.168.0.11` has access to a website hosted on `10.10.10.10` I am able to gain access to the webpage using meterpreter by doing:

```
meterpreter> run autoroute -s 10.10.10.0/24
meterpreter> run portfwd add -l 8080 -p 80 -r 192.168.0.11
```

and then `localhost:8080` in a web browser. From here I can use meterpreters TCP scanners to see there are other machines on the `10` network.

My question is, how can I then attempt to gain access to another machine, say brute force `10.10.10.11' ssh port?

Also in an effort to gain a better understanding of what metesploit is doing, how could I also achieve this setup with proxychains? and would this allow me to use the kali tools on my host: `192.168.0.10` directly on the target network `10` network?

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a networking question than a security question. To understand that metasploit is doing, you need to understand TCP/IP routing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a meterpreter payload to route into another network, but this is not a traditional route, as it will only forward TCP connections. As per the doc I think you were following.

> My question is, how can I then attempt to gain access to another machine, say brute force `10.10.10.11' ssh port?

Within metasploit, it should use its internal routing information and you can aim SSH related tools to 10.10.10.11:22 and it should work via the pivoting payload.

> Also in an effort to gain a better understanding of what metesploit is doing, how could I also achieve this setup with proxychains? and would this allow me to use the kali tools on my host: 192.168.0.10 directly on the target network 10 network?

You need to run an auxiliary socks proxy from within metasploit (considering you're using the same exploitation and pivoting method) using something like `auxiliary/server/socks4a`, to which you aim `proxychains` at and use it with cmdline tools. Ultimately you could run from your command line something like this:
`proxychains nmap -sT -F 10.10.10.22`.

Here's some resources for you to study and experiment:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/metasploit/metasploit_pivoting.htm [pretty sure you know this one]
- https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/proxytunnels/
- https://nullsweep.com/pivot-cheatsheet-for-pentesters/
- http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Those resources where exactly what i was looking for. I didnt realise metersploit had a built in 'proxychains' module

Comment: it doesn't, proxychains is a tool to be used outside meterpreter.